# Trying to configure Xunit test project . but pipeline unable to find tests

Tags: azure, azure-devops

[debug]adjustedPattern: 'D:\a\1\s**/*[Tt]ests/*.csproj'

[debug]0 matches
final results

[warning]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.

[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=warning;]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.

Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated to contain .Net Core 3.x (3.1) SDK/Runtime along with 2.1.

Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 3.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous
versions.

Some commonly encountered changes are:
If you're using `Publish` command with -o or --Output argument, you will see that the output folder is now being created at root directory rather
than Project File's directory. To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer
here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting

[section]Finishing: Test

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your search pattern, just modify the search pattern to correct format and this issue would get resolved.

In most scenarios:

1.Change to the pattern to `**/*.csproj` (Use `'**/*.csproj'` if it's yaml pipeline)

Or be more specific:

2.Change the pattern to `**/YourProjectName.csproj` (Use `'**/YourProjectName.csproj'` if it's yaml pipeline)

If you're using classic pipeline, you may need to unlink the box first to edit the element:

[image]